# TextField in List loses focus when ForEach adds rows

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-foreach

I've read many similar questions here about `ForEach` causing `TextField` to lose focus, but all of those hinge on the `ForEach` using a binding parameter. This one doesn't.

I have a `List` with the first row as a `TextField`, and then a `ForEach` that shows rows based on matching items with the text in the `TextField`. Here's the code:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var textValue = ""

    var body: some View {
        List {
            // Text Entry
            TextField("Person:", text: $textValue)

            // Suggestions
            ForEach(suggestions, id: \.id) { onePerson in
                Text(onePerson.id)
            }
        }
    }
    
    var suggestions: [PersonSuggestion] {
        guard !textValue.isEmpty else { return [] }
        
        let existingPeople = Person.allCases
            .filter { $0.rawValue.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(textValue) }
            .sorted(using: KeyPathComparator(\.rawValue))
            .map { PersonSuggestion.existing(person: $0) }
        
        if textValue != existingPeople.first?.id {
            return [.new(name: textValue)] + existingPeople
        } else {
            return existingPeople
        }
    }
}
```

And the supporting types:

```swift
enum Person: String, Hashable, CaseIterable {
    case John
    case Paul
    case George
    case Ringo
}

enum PersonSuggestion: Hashable, Identifiable {
    case new(name: String)
    case existing(person: Person)
    
    var id: String {
        switch self {
        case .new(let name):
            "+ " + name
        case .existing(let person):
            person.rawValue
        }
    }
}
```

When I enter the first letter into the text field, the `ForEach` goes from zero rows to a non-zero number (which is expected), and the text field loses focus (not expected). When I re-focus and then type more, and the number of rows goes down, the focus is not lost any more. It only gets lost when the text goes from empty to non-empty.

If I put the `TextField` and the `ForEach` in separate `Section`s, the problem doesn't occur. But I need all the rows to be in one section, so that's no good.

As stated at the top, all the other questions like this I've found on StackOverflow are about `ForEach`'s that use a binding parameter. This one doesn't, and none of the mentioned solutions have worked. What am I missing here? Can you help me find a better way to fix this? :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this is intentional - might be a SwiftUI bug.

This seems to be caused by giving an empty collection to `ForEach`. If you just do:

```
if !suggestions.isEmpty {
    ForEach(suggestions) { onePerson in
        Text(onePerson.id)
    }
}
```

then there is no problem, despite the code looking really stupid :D

Comment: Thanks! That did it. I'd rather my code look a little stupid than the app look really stupid ;-)  I guess I'll have to be more careful with `ForEach` than I realized. It's causing other problems in my full project where I originally found this problem, but those are for another time.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned this approach prevents the 'TextField' from losing focus as each 'Section' is treated as a separate entity within the 'List'.

try this

```
struct ContentView: View {
@State private var textValue = ""

var body: some View {
    List {
        Section(header: Text("Person:")) {
            TextField("Enter a person:", text: $textValue)
        }

        Section(header: Text("Suggestions")) {
            ForEach(suggestions, id: \.id) { onePerson in
                Text(onePerson.id)
            }
        }
     }
  }
}
```