# List with sections is not updated. Is this a bug in iOS16?

Tags: swiftui

I encountered a ridiculous bug and reproduced it using an empty project. List with sections does not refresh itself via published variable in some cases. This issue only exists in iOS16, iOS 15 and iOS17 works fine.

Code show as below.

```
//AppOB.swift
class AppOB: ObservableObject {
    static let shared = AppOB()
    @Published var token: String?
}

//App.swift
@main
struct SwiftUIDebugApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(AppOB.shared)
        }
    }
}

//ContentView.swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var ob: AppOB
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if ob.token != nil {
                ListView()
            }
            else {
                LoginView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Modify any commented line below and the program will run as expected.

```
//LoginView.swift
struct LoginView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var ob: AppOB
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                Button{
                    login()
                } label: {
                    Text("login")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    func login() {
        withAnimation { // remove withAnimation works fine
            ob.token = "123"
        }
    }
}

//ListView.swift
struct ListView: View {
    @State var list: [String] = []
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView { // or remove navigation works fine
            List {
                Section { // or remove section works fine
                    ForEach(list, id: \.self) {item in
                        HStack {
                            Text(item)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
//            .id(UUID()) // or add id works fine
        }
        .onAppear {
            getList()
        }
    }
    func getList() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) { // simulate network requests
            self.list = ["apple", "pear"]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If it works on iOS 17 then I'd assume it's a bug that got fixed. In any case, if you are on iOS 16, try using `NavigationStack` instead. Perhaps that will make a difference.

Comment: @Sweeper Indeed. NavigationStack does work. Unfortunately, the minimum requirement is to support iOS 15..  SwiftUI is too difficult to be compatible with..

Comment: Try wrapping the `ForEach` with `if !list.isEmpty { ... }`. I know empty `ForEach`es sometimes behave in weird ways (see [my answer to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77333640/5133585)).

Comment: @Sweeper Thanks. I've tried this way before.. now breakpoints in the foreach statement works, but the list never gets refreshed. I temporarily used the `.id(UUID())` to disable the animation as a workaround. Still thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

`ListView()` has no parameters and is cached. You might be lucky and it could be updated sometimes, but in general you need to have some reference from the model used in ListView with the models of the parent views.